# Implement a function similar to async

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function `foo` that returns a `future`. `foo` will register a callback which will be called after `foo` returns.

```
future<int> foo() {
    promise<int> p;
    future<int> ret(p.get_future());
    thread(bind([] (promise<int> &&p) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
        p.set_value(10);
    }, move(p))).detach();
    return move(ret);
}

int main()
{
    auto f = foo();
    cout << f.get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it seems like that `std::bind` forwards the rvalue reference as a lvalue reference so that can not be successfully compiled. Is there any way to fix it?

---

I have to write an ugly class to move the `promise` object:

```
template<typename T>
class promise_forward {
    promise<T> promise_;

public:
    promise_forward(promise<T> &&p) : 
        promise_(move(p)) {}

    promise_forward(promise_forward<T> &&other) : 
        promise_(move(other.promise_)) {}

    operator promise<T> () {
        return move(promise_);
    }
};

future<int> foo() {
    promise<int> p;
    future<int> ret(p.get_future());
    thread(bind([] (promise<int> &&p) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
        p.set_value(10);
    }, promise_forward<int>(move(p)))).detach();
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = foo();
    cout << f.get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The functions type is future<int> and you return a future<int> &&.

Answer (score 1):

You, basically, doesn't need `std::bind` here (well , I believe so =)).
Here is a quick draft of a simplest async task launcher. It almost same as yours, but, just a little more generic: it can accept any function objects and it is less intrusive: function objects doesn't know nothing about promises or threading at all.

There are may be mistakes (I'm quite sure they are). And, of course, it is far far away, from `std::async` implementation (which, generally, more than just thread launcher, but, ideally, have a huge thread management back-end).

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>


template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type> my_async(Function && f, Args && ... args)
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type ret_type;

    std::promise<ret_type> p;

    auto fut = p.get_future();


    // lambda in separate variable, just to improve readability 
    auto l = [](Function && f, Args && ... args, std::promise<ret_type> && p)
    {
        p.set_value(f(args...));
    };

    std::thread th(l, std::move(f), std::move(args...), std::move(p));

    th.detach();

    return std::move(fut);

}

int wannaRunAsync(int i)
{
    return i;
};

int main()
{

    auto fut = my_async(&wannaRunAsync, 42);

    auto fut2 = my_async([](int i) -> int { return i; }, 42);

    std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << fut2.get() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I was able to compile and run it with
[g++-4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0935e03b867ea2c) and 
[clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7f7b412410f5c29) but with msvc 2012 and 2013 preview it doesn't even compiles (probably, due to errors).

I've not tested this code at all, so be careful =) Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! `std::bind` must be there because the real code is more complex and `std::thread` just for illustrating my purpose. Unfortunately, I'm using is vs2012 and I have to implement a ugly forward class to move the `promise` object to the lambda.